# "." and "+" not working properly

Tags: python, regex

I have a string, where

```
text='<tr align="right"><td>12</td><td>John</td>
```

and I would like to extract the tuple ('12', 'John'). It is working fine when I am using

```
m=re.findall(r'align.{13}(\d+).*([A-Z]\w+).*([A-Z]\w+)', text)
```

print m

but I am getting ('2', 'John'), when I am using

```
m=re.findall(r'align.+(\d+).*([A-Z]\w+).*([A-Z]\w+)', text)
print m
```

Why is it going wrong? I mean why .{13} works fine, but .+ fails to work in my re?
Thank you!

Comment: Um… both of these regexes return no matches for your test string. Can you post your actual code and sample data?

Comment: After your edit, the text is now going to raise a `SyntaxError` because it's missing the closing quote—but if I fix that, there's again nothing that matches either of your regexps in that text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't actually test this with the sample text and regexps you provided, because as written they clearly should find no matches, and in fact do find no matches in both 2.7 and 3.3.

But I'm guessing that you want a non-greedy match, and changing `.+` to `.+?` will fix whatever your problem is.

As Jon Clements points out in his answer, you really shouldn't be using regular expressions here. Regexps cannot actually parse non-regular languages like XML. Of course, despite what the purists say, regexps can still be a useful hack for non-regular languages in quick&dirty cases. But as soon as you run into something that isn't working, the first think you ought to do is consider that maybe this isn't one of those quick&dirty cases, and you should look for a real parser. Even if you'd never used the `ElementTree` API before, or XPath, they're pretty easy to learn, and the time spent learning is definitely not wasted, as it will come in handy many times in the future.

But anyway… let's reduce your sample to something that works as you describe, and see what this does:

```
>>> text='<tr align="right"><td>12</td><td>John</td> 
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>> text='<tr align="right"><td>12</td><td>John</td>'
>>> re.findall(r'align.{13}(\d+).*([A-Z]\w+).*([A-Z]\w+)', text)
[]
>>> re.findall(r'align.{13}(\d+).*([A-Z]\w+)', text)
[('12', 'John')]
>>> re.findall(r'align.+(\d+).*([A-Z]\w+).*([A-Z]\w+)', text)
[]
>>> re.findall(r'align.+(\d+).*([A-Z]\w+)', text)
[('2', 'John')]
```

I think this is what you were complaining about. Well, `.+` is not "not working properly"; it's doing exactly what you asked it to: match at least one character, and as many as possible, up to the point where the rest of the expression still has something to match. Which includes matching the `1`, because the rest of the expression still matches.

If you want it to instead stop matching as soon as the rest of the expression can take over, that's a non-greedy match, not a greedy match, so you want `+?` rather than `+`. Let's try it:

```
>>> re.findall(r'align.+?(\d+).*([A-Z]\w+)', text)
[('12', 'John')]
```

Tada.

Comment: Glad to know this fixes the immediate problem. Sadly not the long term one, but oh well!

Comment: @JonClements: You're right, I should edit this answer to raise the larger point.

Comment: +1 from me. Good explanation of the regex - great edit - caveat empor I guess

Answer (score 5):

You should really be using a proper HTML parser library for this, ie:

```
>>> a = '<tr align="right"><td>12</td><td>John</td>'
>>> p = lxml.html.fromstring(a)
>>> p.text_content()
'12John'
>>> p.xpath('//td/text()')
['12', 'John']
```

Obviously you'd need to work this better for multiple occurrences...

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.+`, it will match as many characters as it can.  Since the `\d+` only needs to match at least one digit, the `.+` will match `"="right"><td>1"` and leave only the "2" to be matched by the `\d+`.

Your original example is working for your sample data.  If you need to write a regex that works on other data, you'll need to explain what the format of that data is and how you want to decide what parts to extract.

Also, given that you seem to be parsing HTML, you're probably better off using something like BeautifulSoup instead of regexes.

Comment: How is his original example working? The `findall` returns `[]`, with both regexps.

Comment: @abarnet: It looks like he included extra stuff in his regex.  He didn't past the code he was using.  If you remove the middle `.*([A-Z]\w+)` then it works.  I just diagnosed the problem by looking at the regex and the data without actually running it.

Comment: Yes, he either included extra stuff in his regexp or cut stuff out of his string. But either way, the regexp can't match the string. I tested with both 2.7 and 3.3 to make sure, but it's obvious. Meanwhile, if you remove the middle or the end of the regexp, it will match `'2'`, not `'12'`, which means it still doesn't work as he wanted.